# Can Ping RPI 4 but cannot SSH or access any docker containers

Tags: pi-4

I have a rpi4 which has SSH enabled. It also runs my Home assistant inside a docker which is called the supervised installation method of HA. There is also mqtt and other addons working with HA. At times,I find that I am not able to access the HA and the mqtt brocker also becomes unreachable.I thought it would be sme issue with the docker and so I tried to connect with SSH using putty but it gave an error that there was no host. But when tried to ping the RPi with my PC, it was successful. What could be having?

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)